# mssql_query() and mssql server

Tags: php, sql-server

```
@ $db = mssql_connect('127.0.0.1','sa','ijg098u');
if (!$db || !mssql_select_db('test') ) {
    exit('db connect error');
}
$str = "insert into comments(name, comment) values('$name', '$comment')";
if (!mssql_query($str)) {
    exit ('db insert error');
}
```

When $name or $comment has strange character, for example accent character, or CJK character, it fails. But if you echo out $str, and paste it into query analyzer of MS SQL Server Studio and execute, it successes.

It seems the problem must occur in the function call mssql_query. Recently i haven't looked into the source code of that function. Is there a bug in it?

Any comments appreciated.

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php to see is there any error

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for that problem just now -- changing the MS SQL Server collation from some specific kind to "Latin1_gereral binary code point" .  The php scripts mentioned above execute successfully.

It seems that MS SQL Server shall change the query string according to its collation setting.

For English or other Latin language, that problem will never happen. But for many other multibyte language characters, it seems an issue.